# Is it safe to use capped collections as a way to manage space?

Tags: mongodb

Basically, I want to create a chat based system and one of the features is to provide a longer history of the chat per membership level. I don't envision allowing a collection larger than 1GB, that even seems overkill. However keeping them small should also mean I don't need to worry about sharding them.

Basically each 'chat' would be a capped collection. The expectation is if they reach the file storage limit the older items would drop, which is how capped collections work. So it seems to me that creating a capped collection for each chat would be an easy way to accomplish this goal. I would just apply and store an id as the collection name so I can access it.

Is there a reason I shouldn't consider this approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like your data is logically split by `chatId`. It's not clear to me whether the scope of a `chatId` is per user, per chat or per "membership level" so I'll just refer to `chatId` in this answer.

This data could be stored in a single collection with an index on `chatId` allowing you to easily discriminate between each distinct chat when finding, deleting etc. As the size of that collection grows you might reach the point where it cannot support your desired non functionals. At which point, sharding would be suggested. Of course, you might never reach that point and a simple single-collection approach with sensible indexing, hosted on hardare with sufficient CPU, RAM etc might meet your needs. Without knowing anything about your volumes (current and future), write throughput, desired elapsed times for typical reads etc it's hard to say what will happen.

However, from your question it *seems* like an eventual need for sharding would be likely and in a bid to preempt that you are considering capping your data footprint.

It is possible to implement a cap per `chatId` when using a single collection (whether sharded or not), this would require something which:

- Can calculate the storage footprint per `chatId`
- For each `chatId` which exceeds the allowed cap delete the oldest entry and loop until the storage footprint is <= the allowed cap.

This could be triggered on a schedule or by a 'collection write events' listener.

Of course, using capped collections to limit footprint is essentially asking MongoDB to do this for you so it's simpler but there are some issues with that approach:

1. It might be easier to reason about and manage a system with a single collection than it is to manage a system with a large number (thousands?) of collections
2. Capped collections will ensure a maximum size per collection but if you cannot cap the number of discrete `chatId`s then you might still end up in a situation where sharding is required
3. Capped collections is not really a substitute for sharding; sharding is not just about splitting data into logical pieces, that data is also split across multiple hosts thereby scaling horizontally. Multiple capped collections would exist on the **same** Mongo node so capping will limit your footprint but it will not scale out your processing power or spread your storage needs across multiple hosts
4. Unless you are using the WiredTiger storage engine (on MongoDB v 3.x) the maximum number of collections per database is ~24000 (see [the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#Number-of-Namespaces))
5. There are [limitations](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/capped-collections/#restrictions-and-recommendations) to capped collections e.g.

   - If an update or a replacement operation changes the document size, the operation will fail.
   - You cannot delete documents from a capped collection
   - etc

So, in summary ...

If the number of discrete `chatId`s is in the low hundreds then the potential maximum size of your database is manageable and the total collection count is manageable. In this case, the use of capped collections would offer a nice trade off; it prevents the need for sharding with no loss of functionality.

However, if the number of discrete `chatId`s is in the thousands and/or if there is no possible cap on the number of discrete `chatId`s or if the number of discrete `chatId`s is such that it forces you to apply a miserly cap on each then you'll eventually find yourself having to consider sharding. If this scenario is at all likely then I would suggest starting as simple as possible; use a single collection and only move from that as/when the non functionals demand it. By "move from that" I mean something like start off by applying a manual deletion process and if that becomes ineffective (i.e. if the number of discrete `chatId`s is such that it forces you to apply a miserly cap on each distinct `chatId`) then consider sharding.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response, reasons 4 and 5 are enough for me to consider the capped collection approach.